# Using a Lookup Table for Description field with Entity Framework Model First Approach

Tags: c#, entity-framework, enums, asp.net-mvc-5, lookup-tables

I am currently redeveloping a site in MVC5 using EntityFramework6 and am struggling with the database structure in particular transforming the lookupFields from one table to the next. We have a Job Table

```
TABLE [dbo].[Job](
[JobId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[JobStateId] [int] NOT NULL,
```

and a JobState Lookup Table

```
TABLE [dbo].[JobState](
[JobStateId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
```

Now I am trying to use the description from the lookup table when viewing the JobView that has been generated using Entity Framework

```
public partial class Job
{
    public int JobId { get; set; }
    public int JobStateId { get; set; }
    public int JobPriorityId { get; set; }
    public string JobType { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> RunAfter { get; set; }
    public int AttemptCount { get; set; }
    public int MaxAttemptCount { get; set; }
    public int RetryDelayMinutes { get; set; }
    public string ContentXml { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ContentId { get; set; }
    public System.DateTime Created { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> SecondaryContentId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> ParentId { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> SingleChild { get; set; }
}
```

I have created a partial view and added in the JobState Field

```
 [MetadataType(typeof(JobMetadata))]
public partial class Job
{
    [ForeignKey("JobState")]
    public virtual JobState JobState { get; set; }
}
```

and am trying to use this in the View

```
 @foreach (var item in Model)
{
    <tr>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobId)
        </td>
        <td>
            @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.JobState)
        </td>
```

however this does not produce a value.

What would be the best way, with the least amount of code to achieve this?

Should I generate enums from this lookup table and then keep them in sync, or create a relationship between these tables? I have looked into using this [EF to enum package](https://github.com/timabell/ef-enum-to-lookup/blob/master/ExampleUsage/EnumExample.cs) however it requires migration scripts and the Seed() function which has not been created using the Database first approach.

I have also tried creating a partial view for the JobStates

```
@inherits System.Web.Mvc.WebViewPage<TS2.Models.Job>
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m, new SelectList((IEnumerable<TS2.Models.Job>)ViewBag.JobStates,
"JobStateId",
"Description",
Model == null ? 1 : Model.JobStateId),
"Choose--")
```

and then using the editorFor approach in the view, but to no avail.

Can anyone guide me in the right direction?

Comment: What's not know so far to us reading this is "Does this table already exist in the DB or are you using code First?"  If the table exists you can simply use the EF Wizard to create everything you need.  What confused me a bit is you showed the dbo schema but the job class has more fields that the dbo scchema did.  Also one other thing, if the foreign key doesn't exist in the DB you cannot simply add it in the model, you have to "emulate" it at the application layer.

Comment: Looks like u need to write a projection. Can u post your EF LINQ query.

Comment: Hey John, thanks for your comment. At the moment these tables are not actually joined by a foreign key constraint. If this is all that is needed, then I will be able to alter the DB. Hopefully this will gracefully solve the issue. If on the other hand I had no control over changing the database I would be interested in hearing Preet's projection idea, Where would I find my ET Linq query, and what would the necessary changes be?

Comment: It was as simple as adding in the foreign key constraints and updating the model!! Thanks for the advice! I tried multiple ways of doing it via the code, and all it required was a simple database fix! If you want to add your  comment as an answer I can accept it.